# Malware opens up some youtube video in ubuntu

Tags: video, google-chrome, youtube, malware

I am having a very strange problem. While working on ubuntu, suddenly out of nowhere a new chrome tab with a random youtube video opens up and starts playing.

Only relevant issue found on internet is -https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/3-r19adhCO0 but that is for windows.

How to find and clean such malware in ubuntu ?

Comment: also check homepage, popup, and proxy settings in the browser - this could be a simple configuration change in the browser instead of actual malware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to find and clean such malware in ubuntu ?

It could be crapware and not malware (ie. you somewhere agreed on it being started). The 2 generic places to check on this if it only happens in 1 browser:

- Check extensions;
- Check settings, the values set at "on startup";

If it is cross browser check with `ps -ef | grep $USER | more` if you can spot processes you do not expect or hint at being malware. If so you got a security problem and someone was able to get to execute a file on your system.

Comment: thanks, I checked the extensions and there was an extension named "Repeat Youtube". Strangely, I never installed any such extension though.